# Floating elements next to table row

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I'm trying to show two icons next to a table row when I hover over it, it would be the typical edit/delete etc buttons.

I've tried adding an extra column with the icons and positioning it with both relative and absolute, but it'll mess up the style of the first column after it

```
<td class="actions">
    <i *ngIf="editing" (click)="saveEdit()" class="fa fa-floppy-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <i *ngIf="editing" (click)="cancelEdit()" class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</td>
```

```
.actions {
     position: relative;
     right: 5%;
     padding: 0;
     border: 0;
     vertical-align: middle;
}
```

This is what I want to do when hovering over a row
[image: Mockup]

```css
$background: #22304b;
$textColor: #58595b;
$lightBlue: #00b9cd;
$lightBlueDark: #0193a2;
$borderGrey: rgb(219, 219, 219);
$backgroundGrey: rgb(246, 246, 249);
table {
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid $borderGrey;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  
  .header {
    background: $backgroundGrey;
    color: $background;
    padding: 25px 15px 15px;
    border-top: 1px solid $borderGrey;
    border-bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .header:last-of-type {
    border-right: 1px solid $borderGrey;
  }
  tr.row {
    transition: background 0.3s ease;
    padding: 15px;
    .column {
      border-right: 1px solid $borderGrey;
      border-top: 0;
      vertical-align: middle;
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    .column.checkbox,
    .column.centered {
      text-align: center;
    }
    .column:last-child {
      border-right: 0;
    }
  }
  tr.row:nth-child(even) {
    background: $backgroundGrey;
  }
  tr.row:hover {
    background: rgba($borderGrey, 0.7);
  }
}

#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="header">Company</th>
        <th class="header">Role</th>
        <th class="header rate">Start Date</th>
        <th class="header">End Date</th>
        <th class="header rate">Pay Rate</th>
        <th class="header rate">Charge Rate</th>
        <th class="header rate">Holiday Rate</th>
        <th class="header rate">Cost Code</th>
        <th class="header">Supervisor</th>
        <th class="header">Supervisor Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="row">
        <td class="column centered"> name </td>
        <td class="column centered">title</td>
        <td class="column centered">date</td>
        <td class="column centered">date2</td>
        <td class="column centered">10€</td>
        <td class="column centered">10€</td>
        <td class="column centered">10%</td>
        <td class="column centered">blabla</td>
        <td class="column centered">approver</td>
        <td class="column centered">email@email.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row">
        <td class="column centered"> name </td>
        <td class="column centered">title</td>
        <td class="column centered">date</td>
        <td class="column centered">date2</td>
        <td class="column centered">10€</td>
        <td class="column centered">10€</td>
        <td class="column centered">10%</td>
        <td class="column centered">blabla</td>
        <td class="column centered">approver</td>
        <td class="column centered">email@email.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row">
        <td class="column centered"> name </td>
        <td class="column centered">title</td>
        <td class="column centered">date</td>
        <td class="column centered">date2</td>
        <td class="column centered">10€</td>
        <td class="column centered">10€</td>
        <td class="column centered">10%</td>
        <td class="column centered">blabla</td>
        <td class="column centered">approver</td>
        <td class="column centered">email@email.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

[This is what I currently have (Codepen)](http://codepen.io/jabravo/pen/yMoexb)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an additional, absolutely positioned element with the icons *inside* each first `td` (I gave that a class called `.editicons`) and use the following CSS. This makes it invisible by default and visible (left of the row) on hovering the row.

```
td:first-child {
    position: relative;
}
.editicons {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  color: red;
  width: 60px;
  left: -50px;
}
tr:hover .editicons {
  display: block;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/peryea

Comment: **it would be the typical edit/delete etc buttons**, how can he bind function on `pseudo-elements`?

Comment: That works wonderfully but I need the 'x' to be html so I can bind Angular 2 function calls to them

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted but the icons will disappear before I'm able to click on them, how could I make them stay visible for longer?

Comment: Yes, I realized that, so I changed one more thing: I gave the hidden DIVs a width, so now they stay there when you hover them, and you can click the icon links